# Linux powersave governor not controlling CPU frequency as expected (many cores still at 3GHz)

Tags: linux, cpu, cpufreq

I'm want to limit CPU activity on a Thinkpad P1 to extend battery life and prevent fan use.
My Linux kernel is `5.15.0-43-generic` and the distribution is Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy).
The processor is a `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1505M v6` (4 cores × 2 threads/core = 8 threads). The machine is using the `intel_pstate` scaling driver.

I expected these commands to limit all cores to 800 MHz:

```bash
echo "1" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
echo powersave | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
echo 800000 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq
echo 800000 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
```

Instead, `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "MHz"` typically shows 3–6 cores at 3 GHz, e.g.

```bash
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "MHz
cpu MHz     : 800.004
cpu MHz     : 800.006
cpu MHz     : 3000.000
cpu MHz     : 3000.000
cpu MHz     : 800.006
cpu MHz     : 800.006
cpu MHz     : 3000.000
cpu MHz     : 800.006
```

Why am I not seeing all cores hovering around 800 Mhz as expected? Also, there are supposed to be two threads per each of the four processor cores. Why am I seeing an odd number of cores (really, threads) running at 3 GHz?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [controversial bug-feature](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=197009). The correct command to check the CPU frequency in this situation is

```bash
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_cur_freq
```

This will show 800 MHz as expected.